# Правильно ли передаю переменную с помощью JSON?

Tags: ajax, php, json, javascript

Ajax скрипт:

```
    function SendForm() {
//отправка файла на сервер
$$f({
    formid:'reg_form',//id формы, прописанной в html
    url:'registration.php',//адрес на серверный скрипт, такой же как и в форме
    onstart:function () {
        alert('отправляем');
    },
    onsend:function () {
        var error=JSON.parse($errortext);
        alert(error);
    }
});
}
```

registration.php:

```
<?php

//огромнейший скрипт проверки

if($errors==1)
    {
    echo json_encode($errortext);
         } 
?>
```

Что я делаю не так?...

Comment: @lordvakar, проявите уважение к отвечающим — приведите код в порядок. Удалите закомментированные, ненужные строки, исправьте форматирование.

Comment: @xEdelweiss , действительно прошу прощения. Я совсем ньюфаг и плохо разбираюсь в редакторе. Научился только выделять код и призывать с помощью собаки. А на счёт закомментированных строк, это я просто устал за весь день. Извиняюсь.

Comment: @lordvakar, не принимайте так близко к сердцу :)

Comment: если $errortext это просто строка, то json_encode просто возьмет ее в кавычки

Comment: @donkey А так в коде нету ошибок?

Comment: а кто такой `$$f()` ? $errortext not defined тоже,